# I want to try my first Facebook project .. is this possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to start to get my hands dirty with the Facebook API.  I have a personal project that I would like to link it in to.  Could I get some feedback?

What I have is a site listing musicians in the live jazz/blues/soul/funk scene in Berlin, Germany.  I have the artists register and they are displayed on a "wall" of artists - a large grid of thumbnail pics and short descriptions.  As you hover over the small profiles, a large sidebar window populates with further data about the artist including influences, instruments played, availability, links to material, etc.  The "wall" can also be filtered in a variety of ways.  For example, search for only guitarists, and non-guitarists fade to near-opacity.  Or text-search "Ornette Coleman" and only musicians influenced by Coleman will be shown, the others fade away into near-opacity. Availability can be shown to help musicians find jam partners or bandmates.  Musicians also indicate who they play with regularly, so the "network" of any individual artist can be shown as well.  It's pretty sweet, if I do say so myself. - and the most advanced thing I've tried to date.

So .. I would like to try my hand at the Facebook API.  I would say I'm intermediate PHP/Javascript, but I have no experience with Facebook.

What kind of info could I incorporate into this?  Most of the musicians have Facebook pages.    I guess I would love to grab upcoming gig information which I could list with the artist info - and possibly sort the "wall" so that musicians playing in the near future are listed nearer to the top, other not so active musicians listed towards the bottom.

I would love to incorporate a "like" functionality as well.

Problem - not every artist will have a Facebook page.

Could anyone tell me what would be feasible?  Specifically, would it be possible for *some* users to link to their Facebook pages and grab upcoming gig information from that?

Or if anyone has any other suggestions to try or good resources to go to.. I am all ears.  If there is no realistic and useful way to integrate then I will just go ahead and close up the project and move on to something else.  I am starting to go through the developer pages tonight.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can create an app that asks the user for permission to access their events. This app will be able to read all sorts of information about their events: dates, times, locations, link to event page, etc. Then ask the musicians to install and authorize this app. It's as simple as that. Your website would aggregate all of the information from all the musicians that authorized your app.

Comment: Thanks for that.  But it seems like it may be tricky to have the site combine Facebook users and non-facebook users, no?  And I'm not sure how to split the registration process.. I need a lot of info that is not available through FB (what instrument is played, etc) and it would have to be manually entered during a "normal" registration process.  I am imagining I would have a normal mySQL-system, and then log a reference to the users Facebook account (along with access info) which I would use for querying for certain info?

Comment: Combining Facebook and non-facebook users shouldn't really be too hard. If you need help with designing the database, it would make sense to ask a new question here on stackoverflow, for example: "how do I create a mysql database that combines facebook and non-facebook users?"

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to grab data from musicians' Facebook pages and add that data to your current website?

If that is correct, then you don't need any interaction with Facebook users at all.  You would simply create an app and have it query Facebook Pages* at scheduled times.  From there, it is up to you to integrate the JSON data into your database.

As for 'Likes,' you'll probably want to lookup 'Social Plugins.'

*You could do this by using FQL to query this table: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/ .  Look at the list, especially for rows with " Applicable to Bands" descriptions.